# I get this error while installing Mediapipe python in command prompt

Tags: python, pip, mediapipe

The following is the error:- ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe........ My version is 64 bit and the latest one 3.11.0 and also the pip is of the latest version.

I was installing mediapipe thorugh command prompt and this happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current latest version mediapipe 0.8.11 [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/0.8.11/#files) for Python 3.7-3.10. Not for 3.11 and no source code.

The bottom line is: don't be so quick to upgrade your Python, wait until all 3rd-party libraries you use are caught up.

Downgrade your Python. Or try to [build from sources](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/python#building-mediapipe-python-package).

Comment: Thanks I installed Python 3.8.5 now it works